# Group which is not cyclic

Tags: group-theory

We know that the group $U(2^n)$ is not cyclic for $n \geq 3$.
But I want to prove that $U(n^2-1)$ is not cyclic for $n>2$.
Please help me

Comment: Can you please tell us what you have tried? Do you know any strategies for proving a group is not cyclic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that 1,-1,n,-n belongs to $G$. As $n$ is coprime to $n^2 - 1$ because $$n*n + (-1)(n^2 - 1) = 1.$$
And all of these elements satisfy ${x^2=1}$ and this is certainly not true in cyclic group